# How to change the column width in wpf spreadsheetgear workbook to exactly 1 inch

Tags: c#, wpf, spreadsheetgear, column-width

I want to set the column widths of some selected columns to 1 inch exactly. However I am having difficulty in figuring out the unit SSG uses to set column width.

I tried "Points" i.e 1 inch = 72 points. But the column width was more than 1 inch in this case.

```
double colWidth = 1; //1 inch

IRange selectedRange = workBookViewControl.RangeSelection; //this has the columns needed to change the width

selectedRange.ColumnWidth = colWidth * 72; //72 is the conversion of inches to points(pt)
```

This seems wrong..

Can anyone please help me in figuring out the constant/unit to multiply to get the desired result.

I know this question is vague but this is all I have.

I will be very happy to provide anymore details if needed.

Regards,

Prashanth

Answer (score 2):

I contacted spreadsheet gear for support on this issue and this is the reply i got from them.

Hello Prashanth,

There are two properties in the IRange interface that deal with column widths:

·         IRange.Width – read-only, returns the width of the range in points.

·         IRange.ColumnWidth – getter and setter – you would use this to set a columns width, in Character Units.

As mentioned above, IRange.ColumnWidth in SpreadsheetGear (and Excel) is not specified in absolute units such as inches or points.  Instead, they use the concept of a “Character Unit” which is dependent on the default font used by the current workbook.  To be more specific, a Character Unit is roughly the width of a “0” character using the “Normal” style for the workbook (available from workbook.Styles["Normal"].Font for a given workbook object).  Note that padding is also added into the width of a cell, so this is an approximation.

Other column width complications can arise for scenarios where you use SpreadsheetGear to generate a workbook that will be viewed in Excel (or vice-versa), and you have set and expect specific column widths.  For such cases you might see slight discrepancies in the actual width of the columns when viewed in Excel and our own WorkbookView.  This typically becomes more noticeable the wider a column gets.  The reason is that the font metrics that we use in .NET to measure text (from GDI+) are slightly different from those used by Excel to measure text (from native GDI).  Since column widths are totally dependent on these measurements, there will be variation between our two environments.

Bottom-line, you might be able to write your own routine that uses IRange.Width/ColumnWidth, through trial-and-error, approximates a 1-inch wide column (I don’t have sample code that demonstrates this), but I doubt you will be able to guarantee a 1-inch wide column exactly, and for all cases.  The moment the “default” font for your workbook changes, your column widths will change accordingly.  Also, the current Zoom for a worksheet could obviously affect the visual width of a column on screen.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

In WPF the default measurement is device px not points try * 96.

1 inch = 96px

Comment: Hi Kenjara, I wanted something particular to spreadsheet gear column width. Here if I am applying 1inch = 96px then I am seeing the desired result is way more than 1 inch.